# Equivalent for the "pid file" stanza in newer versions of upstart

Tags: linux, ubuntu, daemon, upstart

I'd like to be able to use upstart to manage daemons where I don't have complete control over the forking behaviour. The "pid" stanza is removed as of version 0.3.9, so I can't point it at a pid file. What is the correct way to go about this? Do I have to write a wrapper script that issues SIGSTOP?

Answer (score 2):

Read this section of the Upstart Cookbook very carefully: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#expect

In a nutshell, if your daemon forks once, use "`expect fork`". If it truly daemonizes (double-forks), specify "`expect daemon`".

Comment: As mentioned, I don't have complete control over the forking behaviour. I can't know how many times the application will fork before getting to the true process. I *do* have a pid file, however, and it seems strange that there is no way to communicate this information to upstart.

Comment: @mispy: well, that's design of upstart: to be able to reliably monitor a daemon, it needs to know its forking behaviour and pid files do not help (as pids they contain *can* differ from reality).

Comment: The fun part is when you are experimenting to figure out how many forks to expect, upstart can wedge completely in such a way that it blocks reboot and necessitates a power cycling of the system.  Being able to check a pid file, which has worked forever, would be a reasonable feature.